# application timeout in 120 - 130 seconds aspnet mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, ef-core-2.0, asp-net-core-spa-services

my application timesout in 120 t0 130 seconds, i tried the following. 
1. web.config change

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" executionTimeout="500" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

2. Added sql timeout EF Core

   command.CommandTimeout = 100;
3. changed on IIS

   Connection Time out 900
4. added  asynctimeout attribute on controller for int.mex value
5. Added httpclient connection timeout to 4 minutes

i 've two application 1. asp net web  calling asp net cocre api

both hosted on IIS both had same settings

Comment: Just to clarify: After everything you have tried, do you still have timeout problems?

Comment: unfortunately yes,

Comment: `CommandTimeout = 100` <  `120-130`, isn't it?

Comment: yes it is, i had 500 seconds all over , that was to tell the approaches i used

Comment: Does it happen for one particular query or for multiple? Do you use linked servers by any chance?

Comment: also added keepalivetimeout in usekresteloptions  still it did not change any thing , am i missing any other configuration ?

Comment: it happens to all queries and yes they are  dtwo different servers ,

Answer (score 0):

**requestTimeout="00:10:00"** 
this is missing in web.config

this changes everything, make sure to keep other changes fi required.